# RavenDB: Can't extract value from expression of type: Parameter

Tags: c#, ravendb

Running this query on RavenDB

```
var syncContacts = session.Query<SyncContact>()
    .Customize(c => c.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
    .Where(s => !Processing.Contains(s))
    .OrderBy(s => s.DateTimeStamp)
    .Take(64)
    .ToList();
```

throws this exception: "Can't extract value from expression of type: Parameter"

Processing is a property defined as

```
public List<SyncContact> Processing { get; set; }
```

This code is attempting to exclude all the SyncContact items in the Processing list from coming back in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say each `SyncContact` has an Id, you might be able to write the where clause this way instead:

```
.Where(s => !s.Id.In(Processing.Select(p => p.Id)))
```

Hope this helps!